# print binary file on browser

Tags: java, jsp, file-io, audio-streaming, binaryfiles

I am developing my project in JSP/SERVLET.
I have Audio tag in HTML

```
<audio src=" player.jsp "/>
```

player.jsp is needed to play from custom starting duration like 01:24
I want my player.jsp to read the file and print it so that HTML audio can read/play it.

I already wrote this code. but it is not working.

```
response.setHeader("Content-Type","audio/mpeg");
String path1 = "C:\\1.mp3";
File fileFileName = new File(path1);

InputStream in = new FileInputStream(path1);
long length = fileFileName.length();

byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) length];

int offset = 0;
int numRead = 0;

while (offset < bytes.length && (numRead = in.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length - offset)) >= 0) {
    offset += numRead;
}
    String file = new String(bytes);
    out.println(file);
```

Please help me:

1. Make this code work?
2. How to find the duration of an mp3 file?
3. How to start from custom duration?

Comment: You need to understand more about HTML. Audio, and images, are not made available by printing them in the HTML. They are made available through separate resources.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make the audio play from a custom start time is to use the JavaScript API:

```
<audio id="player" src="player.jsp" type="audio/mpeg" data-start-time="45">
    Audio not supported
</audio>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var player = document.getElementById('player');
    player.currentTime = player.getAttribute('data-start-time');
    player.play();
</script>
```

The script will run after the player is loaded and set the track current time to 45 seconds. Note that I moved the start time to a custom attribute, so it could be set dynamically with JSTL: `data-start-time="${startTimeSec}`.

The full clip duration can also be obtained with JavaScript. In terms of the previous example it's `player.duration` property.

Finally, if you want to use a servlet for dynamic audio loading, you should return an output stream of bytes, not a string as you do now.

```
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
out.write(bytes, 0, numRead);
out.flush();
out.close();
```